# PyQt5: A custom subclass of QWidget cannot fill entire window, but QWidget() can, what's the difference?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, qwidget

class customWidget(QWidget):
def **init**(self, parent=None):
super(customWidget, self).**init**(parent)

class Window1(QWidget):
def **init**(self):
super(Window1, self).**init**()
self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
self.initUI()

```
def initUI(self):
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    a = customWidget(self)
    a.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
    vbox.addWidget(a)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP88V.png)
class Window2(QWidget):
def **init**(self):
super(Window2, self).**init**()
self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
self.initUI()

```
def initUI(self):
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    a = QWidget(self)
    a.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
    vbox.addWidget(a)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swyjx.png)

what's the difference between fig1 and fig2, how can i make the same effect in window with window2

Comment: the difference between
a = QWidget(self)
 a = customWidget(self)

Comment: The difference is that `customWidget` is a subclass, and by default the background color is shown only for pure QWidget instances: *any* QWidget subclass needs to draw the background only if it "wants" to.